# how to decrypt base64 image and set to image using ajax in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to set base 64 image (retrieved from database) to the image box using ajax code
in asp.net.

thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you're mixing some terms there. You don't decrypt using Ajax.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please publish code and errors/issues you've encountered so that other users can assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is my first post :)

you dont need to convert base64 data to convert it to an image

The below should work:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + "Base64Data";
```

via AJAX:

```
$.ajax(
{ 
url : 'the_URL', 
processData : false,
}
).always(function(Base64Data){
$("imageID").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64Data);
});
```